# What is the point of creating a symlink in /dev direcory?

Tags: udev, devices, input-devices, sysfs

I understand that you can write custom udev rules to create a symlink in /dev directory.

Wondering what having a symlink in /dev accomplishes?

What is the symlink linking to?

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="myusb"`

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in the unix/linux stackex for anyone who stumbles on this looking for an answer.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756092/whats-the-reason-to-add-a-symlink-to-dev-directory/756094?noredirect=1#comment1440055_756094